# Send and receive data from local client machine to a flask server on an Ubuntu server

Tags: python, flask

Can someone please help me with my query.

On my local machine, I have a server and client implemented in Python. The JSON data is sent from client to server, the server parses the required data out of it and sends the result as JSON file back to the client. This is running fine on my local machine. I now want to implement this flask server on an Ubuntu server and then want to send and receive data. I am trying to use mod_wsgi as explained in

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

I am still not able to get the data back to my local machine. Here is my code:

client.py

```
import sys
import json
import requests
import time
import os
import glob

data_location = 'C:\\Users\\cathy\\Desktop\\data'  # folder containing all the data        
for root, directories, files in os.walk(data_location):
    for directory  in directories:
        loc = (data_location + '/' + directory + '/*')
        all_files = glob.glob(loc)
        for filename in all_files:
            f=open(filename)
            f=f.read().splitlines()
            payload = {'input': f}
            s = json.dumps(payload)
            #res = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/my_data/", json=s).json()
            res = requests.post("http://12.345.678.890/my_data/", json=s).json()
            #time.sleep(10)
            if res['employee_id']:
                print(res['employee_id'])
            if res['name']:
                print(res['name'])
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json
import re
import sys
import os
import time
from parsers import id_parser, name_parser
import spacy
import re
from datetime import datetime#
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
import glob
app = Flask(__name__) 


@app.route('/my_data/', methods = ['POST'])
def parsing_data():
    jsondata = request.get_json()
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    requiredData=data['input']
    employee_id_=id_parser(requiredData)
    name=name_parser(requiredData)

    result = {'employee_id_': employee_id_, 'name':name}
    return json.dumps(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `json.dump()` try using flask `jsonify` method that will be compatible within flask.

```
#......
from flask import jsonify
#......


@app.route('/my_data/', methods = ['POST'])
def parsing_data():
    #.....

    result = {'employee_id_': employee_id_, 'name':name}
    return jsonify(result)
```

I'm not shure if it will help, but try it. :)

Comment: and send the data to the server using `jsonify`method from flask

Comment: Also instead of `request.get_json()` you could use `jsondata= request.json['input']`. Then you could skip these 3 lines `jsondata = request.get_json(), data = json.loads(jsondata), requiredData=data['input']` and then u can use it like this: `requiredData = request.json['input']`

Comment: My code is working fine when I am running both client and server on my local machine. I want to know how can I make my server code run on a remote machine?

Comment: As I understand you run your server.py on ubuntu and you are using client.py on windows and this doesn't work. Does it work when server.py and client.py is on ubuntu? Can you call the server.py from windows using curl for simple 201 responce from ubuntu server.py? And maybe some gateway might be closed or if your using virtual box to host your ubuntu you might need to configure your vbox to allow communications?

Comment: does the server.py in ubuntu receive data? have you tried to print the json you send from client?

Comment: i don't know how to use curl. Can you please tell me what I should write in order to execute curl?

Comment: hi @rolandas the issue has been resolved. There was some issue in the interpreter at the server side which has been fixed now. Thank you so much for your time and efforts! I really appreciate!

Comment: Thanks but after a certain time, it freezes!